# Laravel 5: Eloquent relationship method with conditions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Normal relationship methods don't usually have a condition, and tend to look like this:

```
class StripeCustomer extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'stripe_customer_id');
    }
}
```

In my model I have a condition in the relationship method like so:

```
class StripeCustomer extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        if ($this->type === 'normal') {
            return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'stripe_customer_id');
        } else {
            return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'stripe_customer_charity_id');
        }
    }
}
```

Does Laravel support conditional relationships in Eloquent like above. A lot of the usual methods still work like so:

```
StripeCustomer::get()->first()->user;
StripeCustomer::get()->first()->user()->get();
```

But would the following work predictably:

```
Foo::with('user')->get();
```

The issue here is that I am unsure in how the "with" operator works in Eloquent internally.

A reason I believe it also doesn't work is that the `user()` method needs to be executed for every model. However, when I added a `dump(...)` at the start of the method, I found it was only run once, indicating that `with()` does not work.

Comment: It looks like you have a _polymorphic_ relationship (https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations). It would be easier to tell if you didn’t obfuscate your class and column names so we can see your intention, though.

Comment: @MartinBean It looks like polymorphic relationship puts me on the right track. But I'm unsure how to do this for my use-case. Note that I have edited my question to make it clear of my intention.

Comment: Do you have a `Charity` model or similar?

Comment: No. A `User` basically can have at most 1 stripe customer, and 1 stripe charity customer on the `User` model.

Comment: I’m still a bit confused. Can a `User` therefore have two Stripe accounts connected (a “personal” and charity account)? Or just one or the other?

Comment: A user can have both a "personal" and a "charity" account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't work with `with()`. What do you think will happen when you try to execute the following code:

```php
Foo::with('user')->get();
```

The answer is Laravel will create new instance of `Foo` and try to call `user()` to get the relationship object. This new instance doesn't have any `type` (`(new Foo)->type` will be `null`), therefore your method `user()` will always return `$this->hasOne(Bar::class, 'b_id')` and this relationship object will be used to construct a query.

As you can see this is clearly not what you wanted since only type B users will be eager loaded for all `Foo` rows. What you need to do in this case is create two relationships (one for each type) and accessors (get/set) for user:

```php
class Foo extends Model
{
    public function userA()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Bar::class, 'a_id');
    }

    public function userB()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Bar::class, 'b_id');
    }

    public function getUserAttribute()
    {
        if ($this->type === 'a') {
            return $this->userA;
        } else {
            return $this->userB;
        }
    }

    public function setUserAttribute($user)
    {
        if ($this->type === 'a') {
            $this->userA()->associate($user);
        } else {
            $this->userB()->associate($user);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use `with()` for both relations to utilize eager loading:

```php
$fooRows = Foo::with('userA', 'userB')->get();
...
foreach ($fooRows as $row) {
    $row->user;
}
```

**edit:** 
Since you've edited code in your question the example code in my answer no longer represents your case, but I hope you get the overall idea.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, `with()` works. It runs a subquery on any relation your `user()` method returns. Since your relation already has a constraint, it applies said constraint to the subquery as you'd expect.

Comment: Wait, there is a difference between applying a constraint (such as a `where()`) and returning two different relations based on a property... I wouldn't be so quick to say it works, to be honest.

Comment: Looking at the answer above, 
>This new instance doesn't have any type
You could run `->load()` on an existing model to have it do what you expect.

You'd be better off creating 2 relationship methods though. This way you can eager load whichever you want in an expressive way.

Comment: @Namoshek as long as you return a relationship, your eager loading will work. Just gotta make sure the property is set, which will only be the case if you already have a model instance. Use `->load()` in this case.